# APFS vs Mac OS Extended (Journaled) for external HDD

Tags: external-disk, filesystem, storage, apfs, hdd

Which one between **APFS** and **Mac OS Extended (Journaled)** works better as partition store type for an external HDD (Magnetic Storage) that will be accessed over USB from macOS only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

APFS is known to not perform well on spinning disk drives (non SSDs).

- Developer of Carbon Copy Cloner:
  [An analysis of APFS enumeration performance on rotational hard drives | Carbon Copy Cloner | Bombich Software](https://bombich.com/blog/2019/09/12/analysis-apfs-enumeration-performance-on-rotational-hard-drives)
- OWC/MacSales (who probably know more about Mac hardware than some people who work for Apple:
  [Using APFS On HDDs ... And Why You Might Not Want To](https://blog.macsales.com/43043-using-apfs-on-hdds-and-why-you-might-not-want-to/)

Comment: Does that mean Mac OS Extended (Journaled) performs better than APFS for spinning disk drives?

Comment: Yes, that is the other alternative that most people would use.