# APFS vs Mac OS Extended (Journaled) for Time Machine Backup on external HDD

Tags: backup, time-machine, external-disk, filesystem, apfs

Which one between **APFS** and **Mac OS Extended (Journaled)** performs better as partition store type for Time Machine backup in an external HDD (Magnetic Storage over USB connectivity)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note this answer now depends on the version of OSX/macOS you have.

This answer is  for macOS Catalina and earlier versions - Big Sur now can use APFS - see  Apple's [Types of disks you can use with Time Machine on Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mh15139/mac) You can also use HFS+ as before.

You **can't use APFS** as a Time Machine target:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202784#format

Time Machine drives **must** be HFS+. That will likely change in the future but currently it is HFS+ only.

Answer (score 1):

Now it can be done:

macOS 11.0 Big Sur: The Ars Technica review
…in Big Sur, Time Machine does make the leap from using HFS+ to using APFS…
https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2020/11/macos-11-0-big-sur-the-ars-technica-review/9/

Comment: better to quote Apple documentation rather than a third party

Comment: Given the incredibly poor job that Apple does of maintaining documentation on the web, and considering that Ars has macOS reviews going back 20 years, I think I'd actually prefer Ars. Here's a Wayback Machine link just in case: https://web.archive.org/web/20210105104812/https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2020/11/macos-11-0-big-sur-the-ars-technica-review/9/

Comment: Yes I have learned on Apple's document slide - I made an internet archive copy too when I linked to the page in my edit of the other answer

Comment: I have read that APFS is designed for SSDs and is not so good for spinners.  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/398901/apfs-vs-mac-os-extended-journaled-for-external-hdd  I think I read something similar in an Apple support document.